# git checkout error: pathspec '?0c69153...' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, powershell

Using Powershell, i'm trying to checkout a specific git commit using a variable.

Without the variable, it works well as expected:

```
> git checkout 0c69153xxxxx
Note: switching to '0c69153xxxxx'.

[...]

HEAD is now at 0c69153
```

Now, in my script I compute dynamically the commit sha and save it in a variable.

I checked the content of the variable and it's ok:

```
> $commit_sha
0c69153xxxxx

> $commit_sha.GetType().Name
String
```

But now the same command using the variable doesn't work:

```
git checkout $commit_sha
error: pathspec '?0c69153xxxxx' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

why `checkout` command think I want to use `pathspec`?
How can I do the checkout using my variable?

Thanks

Comment: The `?` in your error message implies that your `$commit_sha` variable contains a string that contains _more_ than just `0c69153xxxxx `

Comment: Ah! Thank you!!  I trim the string and realized there was hidden whitespace at the end.

Comment: Glad to hear the mystery is solved.

Answer (score 1):

`$commit_sha` contained a hidden whitespace.

Solution was to trim the variable before using it:

```
> $commit_sha.Length
41
> $commit_sha = $commit_sha.Trim()
> $commit_sha.Length
40
> git checkout $commit_sha
Note: switching to '0c69153xxxxx'.

[...]

HEAD is now at 0c69153
```